# How to choose a Controller in the routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

In Laravel 4.2, I have the following route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::post('/account/edit', array(
        'as'   => 'account-edit',
        'uses' => 'UserController@accEdit'
    ));
});
```

I have a `ClientController` and an `AdminController` for common user and admin, respectively.

Assuming that I know the user type (`Auth::getUser()->getType()`), how can I replace the `UserController` with the correct controller without adding extra logic to routes class? Can this be done with filters?

I'm trying to avoid an extra controller between the routes and the final controller.

Comment: Maybe, when you downvote a question, you could explain why in order to improve it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not necessary to create two user controller. Just use **middleware** to limit the access rights of clients. By this way, you can keep the original `UserController`.

You can add **IsAdmin.php** in the middleware.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class IsAdmin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (Auth::getUser()->getType() === 'admin')
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

}
```

In **kernel.php**, you need declare your middleware.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // some other middlewares
        'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin',
    ];
```

Then, add the following statements in `public function __construct` of the **UserController.php**

```
$this->middleware('admin', ['only' => ['OnlyForAdmin1','OnlyForAdmin2']]);
```

Thus, clients will have no access to the function `OnlyForAdmin1` and function `OnlyForAdmin2`.

Comment: Tks @HongbinWangI, but don't think Laravel 4.2 supports Middlewares

Comment: I am sorry that I have ignored your laravel version.